# In firebase authentication, is there a way to remove a custom claim?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

In order to set a custom claim, one uses:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{claim:value});
```

There does exist

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid,{claim:value});
```

...but I'm not exactly clear on how the two are different, and neither one seems to get at actually removing a previously applied custom claim.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims):

> You can delete a user's custom claims by passing null for `customClaims`.

So this should delete the claim:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {claim: null});
```

As others have pointed out **the API has changed** and the current way to set custom claims from Node.js is:

```
getAuth()
  .setCustomUserClaims(uid, { admin: true })
  .then(() => {
    // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
    // next time a new one is issued.
  });
```

Check the linked documentation for more code samples, that are also more likely to be up to date than anything I type here. :)

Comment: That was fast! Jen Person was right, you're the king of firebase stackoverflowage.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. In this case my work wasn't much more than opening the linked page about custom claims, search for `remove` (which gave no relevant hits) and then `delete`.

Comment: Using the latest admin SDK, I had to use             `admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, null);`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what if just one of many claims need to be removed? full read and then write?

Comment: Yup, there is no API to just send just the update, so read, modify in memory, write is the process.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Your answer should be update to use `setCustomUserClaims`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Admin SDK.

```javascript
// This fails with `INVALID_CLAIMS`

return {
  customClaims: null,
}
```

Answer (score 9):

[@FrankvanPuffelen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48175562/2037924) no doubt was the correct one at the time he answered it, however, as it stands today (Nov 30, 2020) the 2nd parameter of [the `updateUser` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#updateuser), called `properties`, is an [`UpdateRequest` interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UpdateRequest) that has no `claim` property.

Setting custom claims has now been moved to [the `setCustomUserClaims` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#setcustomuserclaims).

You set them by doing...

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { admin: true });
```

...and the only way you can remove one is by setting the whole object to `null`. There seems to be no way to selectively remove one claim if there are multiple.

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use updateUser for this, I think you still need to call

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {claim:null});
```

Comment: this sets claim attribute to null but doesn't seem to remove it

Comment: @Fakeer I think (though I only recently started using firebase) the old way was to use `updateUser` and the `claim` property appears to have been used to set custom claims, but that seems to have changed now and indeed, the new way is to use `setCustomUserClaims`, however, in latter case the `claim` property is not needed anymore, setting `claim: null` actually sets a custom claim called `claim` to have the value `null` instead.