# How can I remove a custom claim

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have some custom claims like

```
{
  claim1: true,
  claim2: true,
}
```

I want to remove one claim

```
{
  claim2: true,
}
```

[In firebase authentication, is there a way to remove a custom claim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175477/in-firebase-authentication-is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-custom-claim) Here use

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {claim: null});
```

but update user not have claim property.

if I use this, this remove the previous claims and also set null, not removed

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(context.auth.uid, {claim1: null});
```

```
{
  claim1: null,
}
```

Comment: Seems like you know a way to do it. What's the problem?

Comment: You have to delete it like delteing a property of an object. See below.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the UserRecord for the user's UID with [getUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#get-user).
2. Get their existing custom claims from [customClaims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html#optional-custom-claims) property.
3. Make changes to it as needed.
4. Update the modified claims with [setCustomUserClaims()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#setCustomUserClaims).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the claim in question.

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then((user) => {

    const userCustomClaims = user.customClaims;

    if (userCustomClaims["claim1"]) {

        delete userCustomClaims["claim1"];
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, userCustomClaims);

    }
}).catch((error) => {

    console.error(error);

});
```

CMIIW